# How can I get string from text file to an array in batch files?

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, cmd, drag-and-drop

I have a text file like this

myFile.txt:

```
apple 
banana
grapes
```

I want to drag text file to batch file and set variables into an array like this:

```
array[0]=apple
array[1]=banana
array[2]=grapes
```

But i couldn't do that. My problem is not just printing them but i can't even do that. I'll do parse operations at the rest of batch file.
My Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /f %%a in %1 do (
set /a i+=1
set array[!i!]=!a!
)
echo %array[0]%
echo %array[1]%
echo %array[2]%
endlocal
```

Comment: Surely you mean, `set "array[!i!]=%%a"`.

Comment: Did not think the parentheses for the IN clause were optional with the FOR command.

Comment: You've also got an off-by-one issue since you increment i before using it.

Comment: Change the `for` line to `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do (` to avoid trouble with certain characters in path/file names...

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%~1") do (
   set /a i+=1
   set array[!i!]=%%a
)
echo %array[1]%
echo %array[2]%
echo %array[3]%

rem Or:

for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo !array[%%i]!

endlocal
pause
```

I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: @AlperTheCoder, "it doesn't work" is not a quite precise failure description, is it?

Comment: Ops! If the filename may contain spaces or special characters, the `for /f` requires `usebackq` switch, as @aschipfl indicated in a comment...